# Determining a surface of revolution from the metric function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a surface $X(u,v)$ where $(u,v)$ are conformal curvature line coordinates with the first fundamental form
$$ds^2 = \lambda^2(du^2 + dv^2).$$

Does the fact that $\lambda_u = 0$ (or $\lambda_v = 0$) imply that this surface is a surface of revolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose the induced metric of an embedded surface $S$ has the form $ds^{2} = \lambda^{2}(du^{2} + dv^{2})$ for some function $\lambda$ of one variable, and the coordinate curves are principal, i.e., lines of curvature. Does this imply $S$ is a surface of revolution?

No; $S$ could be a cylinder (over an arbitrary curve) parametrized by
$$
X(u, v) = (x(u), y(u), v),\qquad x'(u)^{2} + y'(u)^{2} = 1.
$$

Comment: Are those surfaces really counterexamples, because we have conformal curvature line coordinates. For example, the helicoid and "self-sliding surface" can be parametrized so that the metric function only depends on one variable, but it would not have curvature line coordinates.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood your intent. By "curvature line coordinates", do you mean you also want the coordinate curves to be lines of curvature?

Comment: Right! Where the first and second fundamental forms are diagonalized.

Comment: I'm guessing cylinders may be a degenerate case you want to exclude, but am leaving this edit for now....

Comment: I didn't mention any conditions on the second fundamental form, so I see that the cylinders do satisfy the condition. Thanks.